# Simulate a click (x,y) on a tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, d3.js

I tried to simulate a click on my tree organisation, in general,  when i click on a blue rect, a subpart appear, and now i tried to simulate it and give the x and y of a blue rect, but it doesn't work, the subpart doesn't appear, and i don't know why.

Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Graphique DPGF</title>
    <style>

.node rect {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

#div { display: table-row; }
#div .cell { display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

//Initialisation des variables, marge, hauteur, incrementation 'i' etc ..
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 20},
    width = 400,
    barHeight = 20,
    barWidth = (width - margin.left - margin.right) * 0.8;

var i = 0,
    duration = 0,
    root;


var path = [];   
path[0] = "A.json";
path[1] = "A.json";
path[2] = "A.json";
var value = [];
create_a_tree_obj(path);


/*function multiple_click(e) {
    //onmousemove = function(e){console.log("mouse location:", e.clientX, e.clientY)}
    switch(e.clientX) {
        case (e.clientX >= 0 && e.clientX < 600):
            document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX + 600, e.clientY).click();
            document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX + 1200, e.clientY).click();
            break;
        case (e.clientX >= 600 && e.clientX < 1200):
            document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX - 600, e.clientY).click();
            document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX + 600, e.clientY).click();
            break;
        case (e.clientX >= 1200):
            document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX - 600, e.clientY).click();
            document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX + 1200, e.clientY).click();
            break;
    }
}*/

function add_total_svg(svg, globaldiv) {
    var last_svg = document.querySelector("svg");
    console.log(last_svg.innerHTML);
    var cell = globaldiv.append("div").attr("class", "total");
    cell.append("p").text("Total").attr("style", "font-family: Helvetica");
    cell.append(last_svg);
}


function create_a_tree_obj(path) {
    var i = 0;
    var div;
    var cell;
    var svg_array = [];

    if (i === 0) {
        div = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("id", "div");
    }
    for (i ; path[i]; i++) {
        cell = div.append("div").attr("class", "cell");
        cell.append("p").text(path[i]).attr("style", "font-family: Helvetica");
        svg_array[i] = cell.append("svg")
        .attr("id", "" + i)
        .attr("width", 600) // + margin.left + margin.right)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        add_the_tree_graph(svg_array, path, i);
    }
    //add_total_svg(svg_array[i - 1], div);
}


function add_the_tree_graph(svg_array, path, i) {
    var root = [];

    d3.json(path[i], function(error, json) {
        if (error) throw error;
        for (; path[i]; i++) { 
            root[i] = d3.hierarchy(json);
            root[i].x0 = 0;
            root[i].y0 = 0;
            update(root[i], svg_array[i], "" + i, root);
        }
    });
}    

function update(source, svg_var, svg_id, all_sources) {

  // Compute the flattened node list.
    var nodes = source.descendants();
    var height = Math.max(500, nodes.length * barHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    document.getElementById(svg_id).setAttribute("height", height);

  d3.select(self.frameElement).transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .style("height", height + "px");

  // Compute the "layout". TODO https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/issues/67
  var index = -1;
  source.eachBefore(function(n) {
    n.x = ++index * barHeight;
    n.y = n.depth * 20;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg_var.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 0);

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
      .attr("height", barHeight)
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", function(d) {
      if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
      update(source, svg_var, svg_id, all_sources); //recursion pour re-afficher la page dynamiquement.
    });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("dy", 3.5)
    .attr("dx", 5.5)
    .each(function (d) {
    if(d.data.attributes.indexOf('|') > -1) {
        var beforeText = d.data.attributes.substr(0,   d.data.attributes.indexOf('|')).trim(),
        afterText = d.data.attributes.substr(d.data.attributes.indexOf('|')+1, d.data.attributes.length).trim();

        d3.select(this).append('tspan').classed('beforetext', true).text(beforeText);
        var afterTextSpan = d3.select(this).append('tspan').classed('aftertext', true).text(afterText);

    // position aftertext
        var temp_text = svg_var.append('text').classed('temp_text', true).text(afterText);
        afterTextSpan.attr('x', (288 - afterText.length * 6) - 5)
        temp_text.remove();
    } else {
        d3.select(this).text(d.data.attributes); 
    }
  });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
    nodeEnter.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1);
    node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
    .select("rect")
      .style("fill", color);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .remove();

}
function simulateClick(x, y) {
    jQuery(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();
}
simulateClick(240, 141);

function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

</script>
```

And the A.json file :

```
{"attributes": "DPGF", "children": [{"attributes": "LOT:  nom 13.CVC", "children": [{"attributes": "Tous_DPGF:  Profondeur 1", "children": [{"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 | 100509", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 0.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel | 19.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle debut"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 |     40", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 20.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel | 20.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle chauffage"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 |     44", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 21.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel | 23.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Préambule"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 |     49", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 24.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel |25.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Préambule"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 |     53", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel |26.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel |27.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle production thermique"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 |     93", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 28.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel | 65.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle chauffage"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}, {"attributes": "Tous_DPGF:  Profondeur 2", "children": [{"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 2", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 31.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel | 65.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Échangeur"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 2"}, {"attributes": "Tous_DPGF:  Profondeur 3", "children": [{"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 35.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel| 35.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Manchon"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel |36.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel |36.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Vanne"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel| 37.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel |37.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Thermomètre"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel    | 38.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel| 38.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Sonde"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel  |39.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel   |39.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Soupape"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 40.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel |41.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Pressostat"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel             | 42.0"}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}
```

So the function is at the end of the code (simulateClick), i tried to do it without jQuery and now with but it doesn't work for the two case.

Comment: It is too much code and too much not necessary code to read... Please, read about [mcve].

Comment: Actually i can remove only one function, but the other code is obligatory to display the tree. @CalvinNunes

Comment: So anyone can't help me ? :(

Comment: Try to provide a snippet or a jsFiddle where we can test your code, since it's to big and you can't create a minimal version of it

Comment: True, here is the a plunker of the code where you can try it : https://plnkr.co/edit/Zvmdyq9U3EZuX3xD5Cgq?p=preview @CalvinNunes

Comment: first: your link to jquery is off, so if you check your `devTools > network` you'll see that the jquery is not beign loaded, so it will throw an error. Consider using this link [ https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js ] which is from a newer version

Comment: second: always load jQuery before any other script, so move the jQuery `<script>` load above all other scripts

Comment: third: Please explain what the click should do, when it clicks on `240, 141` what should happen?

Comment: I did the first and second step but it doesn't worked, and when we clicks on (240, 141), it should hide the subpart of the first rect "Poste: Rang Rang 1", and btw thanks again for your helping @CalvinNunes

Answer (score 0):

Couple problems here:

1. In your plunker, `jquery` is not loading because it's link is `http`, but that doesn't really matter (see 2)
2. You should be calling the `click` event the `d3` way and not the `jquery` way.
3. You are calling the event too quickly, before `d3` has built the SVG trees.

Try it like this:

```
function simulateClick(x, y) {
    var s = d3.select(document.elementFromPoint(x, y));
    s.on("click")(s.datum());
}
setTimeout(() => simulateClick(240, 141), 500);
```

Update [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/spL01VMZNTjChZWIY2Cu?p=preview).

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Graphique DPGF</title>
    <style>

.node rect {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

#div { display: table-row; }
#div .cell { display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

//Initialisation des variables, marge, hauteur, incrementation 'i' etc ..
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 20},
    width = 400,
    barHeight = 20,
    barWidth = (width - margin.left - margin.right) * 0.8;

var i = 0,
    duration = 0,
    root;


var path = [];   
path[0] = "https://jsonblob.com/api/c9b64b44-b8ec-11e8-9d42-6fcb3a8ffdcd";
path[1] = "https://jsonblob.com/api/c9b64b44-b8ec-11e8-9d42-6fcb3a8ffdcd";
path[2] = "https://jsonblob.com/api/c9b64b44-b8ec-11e8-9d42-6fcb3a8ffdcd";
var value = [];
create_a_tree_obj(path);


/*function multiple_click(e) {
    //onmousemove = function(e){console.log("mouse location:", e.clientX, e.clientY)}
    switch(e.clientX) {
        case (e.clientX >= 0 && e.clientX < 600):
            document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX + 600, e.clientY).click();
            document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX + 1200, e.clientY).click();
            break;
        case (e.clientX >= 600 && e.clientX < 1200):
            document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX - 600, e.clientY).click();
            document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX + 600, e.clientY).click();
            break;
        case (e.clientX >= 1200):
            document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX - 600, e.clientY).click();
            document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX + 1200, e.clientY).click();
            break;
    }
}*/

function add_total_svg(svg, globaldiv) {
    var last_svg = document.querySelector("svg");
    console.log(last_svg.innerHTML);
    var cell = globaldiv.append("div").attr("class", "total");
    cell.append("p").text("Total").attr("style", "font-family: Helvetica");
    cell.append(last_svg);
}


function create_a_tree_obj(path) {
    var i = 0;
    var div;
    var cell;
    var svg_array = [];

    if (i === 0) {
        div = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("id", "div");
    }
    for (i ; path[i]; i++) {
        cell = div.append("div").attr("class", "cell");
        cell.append("p").text(path[i]).attr("style", "font-family: Helvetica");
        svg_array[i] = cell.append("svg")
        .attr("id", "" + i)
        .attr("width", 600) // + margin.left + margin.right)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        add_the_tree_graph(svg_array, path, i);
    }
    //add_total_svg(svg_array[i - 1], div);
}


function add_the_tree_graph(svg_array, path, i) {
    var root = [];

    d3.json(path[i], function(error, json) {
        if (error) throw error;
        for (; path[i]; i++) { 
            root[i] = d3.hierarchy(json);
            root[i].x0 = 0;
            root[i].y0 = 0;
            update(root[i], svg_array[i], "" + i, root);
        }
    });
}    

function update(source, svg_var, svg_id, all_sources) {

  // Compute the flattened node list.
    var nodes = source.descendants();
    var height = Math.max(500, nodes.length * barHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    document.getElementById(svg_id).setAttribute("height", height);

  d3.select(self.frameElement).transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .style("height", height + "px");

  // Compute the "layout". TODO https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/issues/67
  var index = -1;
  source.eachBefore(function(n) {
    n.x = ++index * barHeight;
    n.y = n.depth * 20;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg_var.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 0);

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
      .attr("height", barHeight)
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", function(d) {
      if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
      update(source, svg_var, svg_id, all_sources); //recursion pour re-afficher la page dynamiquement.
    });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("dy", 3.5)
    .attr("dx", 5.5)
    .each(function (d) {
    if(d.data.attributes.indexOf('|') > -1) {
        var beforeText = d.data.attributes.substr(0,   d.data.attributes.indexOf('|')).trim(),
        afterText = d.data.attributes.substr(d.data.attributes.indexOf('|')+1, d.data.attributes.length).trim();

        d3.select(this).append('tspan').classed('beforetext', true).text(beforeText);
        var afterTextSpan = d3.select(this).append('tspan').classed('aftertext', true).text(afterText);

    // position aftertext
        var temp_text = svg_var.append('text').classed('temp_text', true).text(afterText);
        afterTextSpan.attr('x', (288 - afterText.length * 6) - 5)
        temp_text.remove();
    } else {
        d3.select(this).text(d.data.attributes); 
    }
  });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
    nodeEnter.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1);
    node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
    .select("rect")
      .style("fill", color);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .remove();

}

function simulateClick(x, y) {
    var s = d3.select(document.elementFromPoint(x, y));
    s.on("click")(s.datum());
}
setTimeout(() => simulateClick(240, 141), 1000);

function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

</script>
```

Comment: Well done it works now, thanks you for the advice !!